# C program return codes and && bash symbol?

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix

In bash, we can use the && operator to execute two commands. For example:

```
./foo && ./bar
```

Will first execute `foo`, and only if foo is "successful", it will then execute `bar`. However, this seems counter-intuitive when you consider that C programs, by convention, return 0 or `exit(0)` upon successful completion, which runs counter-intuitive to the behavior of the `&&` operator. (Since in most languages, 0 is considered to be a 'falsey', and thus would stop the second statement from executing.) What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything. You just have to keep in mind that `true` and `false` aren't fundamental concepts in the shell. `success` and `failure` are.

Answer (score 7):

The C language convention that 0 is false and anything else true, is just that, a *convention*. Bash (and unix shells in general), use the opposite convention: 0 is true, anything else is false.

```
$ if ( exit 0 ); then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
$ if ( exit 1 ); then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
$ if ( exit 2 ); then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
```

Because of this, the `true` command always exits with a status of 0, while `false` exits with a status of 1.

```
$ true; echo $?
0
$ false; echo $?
1
```

This can be rather disconcerting for someone who's used to the C convention, but it makes a lot more sense in shell terms that truth=success=zero exit status, while false=failure=nonxero exit status.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing that Bash's `&&` operator is defined thusly:

**command1** `&&` **command2**
**command2** is executed if, and only if, **command1** returns an exit status of zero.

Comment: More importantly, an _exit status of zero_ is _success_ and anything else is a failure. This really means that _command2_ is only executed if _command1_ succeeds.

Comment: The way to remember this is that there can be many reasons for a program to fail, and it's not uncommon to use the exit status to distinguish them. For instance, grep's exit status is 1 if no matching lines were found, but 2 if it failed because of some other problem (e.g. file not found). On the other hand, in C programming, true versus false often corresponds to something versus nothing, and nothing is represented as 0.