# How does && work in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, operators, logic

I'm using `Bash` specifically, but I imagine most shells behave the same way.

I often do

```
hg pull && hg update --clean
```

But it just occurred to me, if `hg pull` returns `0` on success, why does it execute the `hg up` command?

Typically the way the `&&` operator works is that it will only execute the next argument if the previous one was truthy. Is `0` truthy in Bash, or what?

This came up because I tried doing the equivalent in Python, but I had to write it like this:

```
call(['hg','pull']) or call(['hg','update','--clean'])
```

Comment: 0 is considered the successful return code because there is generally only one way for a command to succeed, but many ways ( corresponding to many available non-zero values) for a command to fail. In shell, it helps to think not in terms of "true" or "false", but in terms of "success" or "failure".

Comment: Duplicate of [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714341/c-program-return-codes-and-bash-symbol)

Comment: @chepner: I understand why 0 is considered successful, I just don't understand how `&&` "knows" that if it can also be used in a programming context where 0 is false, and everything else is true.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: You're right. Please vote to close :-) Didn't see that one.

Comment: @Mark: Like I said, don't think in terms of true and false. `a && b` simply means "run `a`, and if it succeeds (i.e., exit code of 0), run `b`. `&&`, despite its appearance, is *not* a Boolean operator in shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As help, you can remember than command when end ***correctly*** (without errors) mean **true**. And his exit codes are **zero**

so,

- **correct** = OK = **true** = exit status 0
- incorrect = BAD = false = exit status > 0

therefore, for example, the correct way deleting all files recursively is

```
$ pwd
/
$ cd /tnp && rm -rf *
cd: can't change directory  #and the rm WILL NOT executed
```

and **not**

```
$ pwd
/
$ cd /tnp ; rm -rf *
cd: can't change directory  #but the rm IS executed (in the root directory)
```

Added:

```
command1 && command2 && command3
               ^            ^
               |            +-- run, only when command2 exited OK (zero)
               |
               +--run only when command1 exited OK (zero)
```

So, command3 will not executed if command1 **or** command2 failed. (when comman1 fails, the command2 will don't execued (fail) so command3 not executed too.

Play with the next

```
run() {
    echo "comand-$2($1)"
    return $1
}

ok() {
    run 0 $1
}
fail() {
    run 1 $1
}

echo "OK && OK && ANY"
ok A && ok B 0 && ok C
echo

echo "OK && FAIL && ANY"
ok A 0 && fail B 1 && ok C
echo

echo "FAIL && ANY && ANY"
fail A && ok B && ok C
echo

echo "OK || ANY || ANY"
ok A || ok B || ok C
echo

echo "FAIL || OK || ANY"
fail A || ok B || ok C
echo

echo "FAIL || FAIL || OK"
fail A || fail B || ok C
echo

echo "FAIL && OK || OK"
fail A && ok B || ok C
echo
```

the result

```
OK && OK && ANY
comand-A(0)
comand-B(0)
comand-C(0)

OK && FAIL && ANY
comand-A(0)
comand-B(1)

FAIL && ANY && ANY
comand-A(1)

OK || ANY || ANY
comand-A(0)

FAIL || OK || ANY
comand-A(1)
comand-B(0)

FAIL || FAIL || OK
comand-A(1)
comand-B(1)
comand-C(0)

FAIL && OK || OK
comand-A(1)
comand-C(0)
```

The last construction is neat, because you can write

```
command1 && (commands if the command1 is successful) || (commands if not)
```

Comment: Like I wrote in the question, I know it returns 0 on success, but how does chaining with `&&` work?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think my misunderstanding was that I knew 0 was a *successful* return code, but I figured `&&` would still treat it as a falsy value because of how it's used in every other language.

Answer (score 2):

The '&&' operator operates in two ways in Bash.

On one hand, it's a [conditional operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html) as you'd expect:

```
if [ $condition1 ] && [ $condition2 ]
#  Same as:  if [ $condition1 -a $condition2 ]
#  Returns true if both condition1 and condition2 hold true...

if [[ $condition1 && $condition2 ]]    # Also works.
#  Note that && operator not permitted inside brackets
#+ of [ ... ] construct.
```

On the other hand, it can be used to concatenate commands, in which case it explicitly checks the return codes of the commands and proceeds down the chain when the value is 0.  [See the doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF).

Comment: Your first example with `[ ... ]` is also an example of `&&` being used to chain two commands. It is not, strictly speaking, the same as  `[ ... -a ...]`, which is a single command with multiple arguments, rather than two separate commands of which the second is execute if the first succeeds.

Comment: When you say it operates in two ways, do you mean that in the context of `[ ... ]` it evaluates `0` as falsy and everything else as truthy?

Comment: to clarify, what chepner said is exactly correct.  the construct `[ ... ]` has a return code: 0 on success (or "truthy") and 1 on failure (or "falsy").  for example, running `[ -d foo ]` by itself and then doing an `echo $?` to see its return code will show you that 0 is returned when the directory exists and 1 is returned when it does not.  so the entire `[ ... ]` is treated the same way as a command.